# after iOS 14 update, react-native bare project app is not working after splashscreen

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, expo, ios14

The error messages I got are below

```
2020-10-08 17:14:00.943709+0900 tessa[68545:298644] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in your Xcode Build Phases.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   tessa                               0x000000010ea77281 -[EXUpdatesEmbeddedAppLoader loadUpdateFromEmbeddedManifestWithCallback:success:error:] + 0
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20106534 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20107789 _dispatch_once_callout + 20
    5   tessa                               0x000000010ea76fd6 +[EXUpdatesEmbeddedAppLoader embeddedManifestWithConfig:database:] + 223
    6   tessa                               0x000000010ea6b36f __115+[EXUpdatesAppLauncherWithDatabase launchableUpdateWithConfig:database:selectionPolicy:completion:completionQueue:]_block_invoke_2 + 89
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2010535b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20106534 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2010c425 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 715
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2010cfa0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 403
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20117591 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 782
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcd8a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcd7b77 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How can I solve this problem ?

I updated xcode, pod, expo-updates ... but right after the app shows splashscreen, it is termiated.
Please let me know how to solve...

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7899

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm still struggling with that.